# Navarna and Dasakshari Chamunda Mantra

Tags: mantras, shaktism, chamunda

- What are the **Rishi**, **Chanda**, **Mantra Devata**, **Bija**, **Shakti** and **Kilaka** of the *Chamunda Navarna Mantra*?

> Although aware of the popular opinion, [this](https://www.manblunder.com/articlesview/chandi-navakshari-mantra-japa) site mentions a completely different set of mantra-angas, unlike [this](https://shrifreedom.org/vedic-astrology/mantra/12749-2/) one which confirms the traditional system.

- Does the addition of *Om* change any of the above details (*Rishi*, *Mantra devata*,etc.)?

> Some sources indicate that addition of the Pranava (Om) changes the mantra to the *dasakshari* **Rama Tarana Mantra** which was used to kill *Ravana*, and therefore changes some *mantra-angas*.

Comment: Lol I didn't recognise you for a moment.

Comment: Learnt from you, keeping a pseudonym is better :P

Comment: @Rickross bro which sastra describes navarna mantra in detail? I checked topics of devi bhagavat and it doesnt seem it is there. Read devi mahatmay once and dont remember it being described there also.

Comment: @Rudra Hi after a long time. Not sure about scriptures. You can read this blog: https://www.manblunder.com/articlesview/chandi-navakshari-mantra-japa

Comment: @Rickross thanks

Answer (score 2):

From the name of the mantra it follows that this mantra should be of nine syllables. If someone adds Pranava to it, then the number of syllables changes...
In many Indian books of the 70-80s, this mantra is given without Pranava. Therefore, I join the question, I would like to see a text-tantra, where this mantra and its traditional description are first given.

Comment: Please share references to your answer